# Determine all the possible combinations between the main elements of the parent list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm working on designing a dataset and I'm facing an issue with a specific part of it. I provided the example below to simplify and relate to my issue.

I have a list of lists

```
list = ['b',['c','g','d'],['h','l']]
```

and I'm interested in a **general solution** to determine all the possible combinations between the main elements of the parent list

Solution needed:

```
['b','c','h']
['b','c','l']
['b','g','h']
['b','g','l']
['b','d','h']
['b','d','l']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools

my_list = ['b', ['c','g','d'], ['h','l']]
print(list(itertools.product(*my_list)))
```

output:

```
[('b', 'c', 'h'), ('b', 'c', 'l'), ('b', 'g', 'h'), 
 ('b', 'g', 'l'), ('b', 'd', 'h'), ('b', 'd', 'l')]
```